# php Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in, how to?

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

i have this function, and i get this error `Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in...`. If i change `eregi` to `preg_match` i get this error `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in...`

```
function getBrowser($userAgent) {
$browsers = array(
    'Opera' => 'Opera',
    'Mozilla Firefox'=> '(Firebird)|(Firefox)', // Use regular expressions as value to identify browser
    'Galeon' => 'Galeon',
    'Chrome'=>'Gecko',
    'MyIE'=>'MyIE',
    'Lynx' => 'Lynx',
    'Netscape' => '(Mozilla/4\.75)|(Netscape6)|(Mozilla/4\.08)|(Mozilla/4\.5)|(Mozilla/4\.6)|(Mozilla/4\.79)',
    'Konqueror'=>'Konqueror',
    'SearchBot' => '(nuhk)|(Googlebot)|(Yammybot)|(Openbot)|(Slurp/cat)|(msnbot)|(ia_archiver)',
    'Internet Explorer 8' => '(MSIE 8\.[0-9]+)',
    'Internet Explorer 7' => '(MSIE 7\.[0-9]+)',
    'Internet Explorer 6' => '(MSIE 6\.[0-9]+)',
    'Internet Explorer 5' => '(MSIE 5\.[0-9]+)',
    'Internet Explorer 4' => '(MSIE 4\.[0-9]+)',
);
foreach($browsers as $browser=>$pattern) {
    if(eregi($pattern, $userAgent)) {
        return $browser; 
    }
}
return 'Unknown'; 
}
```

any ideas on how to fix this. and also i would like a dumbed down explanation on what is happening if you guys dont mind so i can understand

thanks

Comment: please point out why none of the 3939 search results for [deprecated+function+eregi](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Deprecated%3A+Function+eregi%28%29) helped solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if(preg_match("#".$pattern."#", $userAgent)) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to use delimeters. Please read http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php

In this case, the following should work:

```
if(preg_match('`'.$pattern.'`i', $userAgent))
```

Answer (score 1):

`ereg()` is the old way of doing regular expressions in PHP, and PCRE (`preg_match` and other `preg_*`) are faster and more powerful -- which explains why the first one is now deprecated.

Migrating from ereg to PCRE should not be too hard, but there are a couple of differences between the syntaxes accepted by those two engines -- which means you'll probably have to fix several of your regular expressions.

Here, the difference that explains the message you get is that **PCRE expects a delimiter arround the regex**.

For example, your regex should not be `Galeon`, but `/Galeon/`

*And you can use pretty much any character you like as delimiter.*

For more informations :

- [PCRE Patterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php)
- [The full syntax reference](http://Pattern%20Syntax)
- And, most interesting for you : [**Differences from POSIX regex**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php)

Quoting the first point of that last link :

> The PCRE functions require that the pattern is enclosed by
>   [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Answer (score 0):

ereg and preg have different syntaxes. In this case, they are similar enough that you can simply add a delimiter around them and I think it would work.